# AngularJS directive not executing the script tags inside the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I have my directive definition:

```
app.directive('myWidget', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'widgets/widget1.html'
        };
    });
```

Which I use in the following way:

```
<div id="myWidget" class="span4" style="border: 1px solid red;">
      <my-widget></my-widget>
</div>
```

This directive's template contains the following:

```
<script>
    alert("lol");
</script>
```

But the problem is that the javascript tag does not seem to work. I should get the alert() to execute, but nothing happens.

I wonder if this is some type of CORS error, but every file is within the same domain. Moreover, the console shows no error, warning or any other message.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Due to other reasons I already load jquery as you can see: http://i.imgur.com/2DPXp7R.png but it doesn't work.

Comment: Damn, I must import jquery before angular. The import order matters here. Thanks

Comment: The question is, why would you need to write js code in a template script tag, when you can just add, a controller or a link function to your directive?

Comment: I want to be able to extend the behavior of my website with modules. I cannot add a new controller without changing the main app declaration. More specifically, I was integrating the JSTree plugin with my angularjs project, to which I created a directive including the html file having the script which initializes the tree. I also feel that it is impossible to initialize the tree in a controller.